# Track button click in Facebook comments plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

is there any way to track button click in Facebook comments plugin? For example, in order to increase the comments counter in my own database. Is there any callbacks from this plugin? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count using the tag:

> fb:comments-count

See: [Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

**UPDATED**

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) 
{  
   //comment is created
});

FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(response) 
{  
   //comment is removed
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know it, I can count the comments once. But I would like to track the adding/removing comments. That's why I asked about the callback functions.

Comment: Please make you ques clear in future, what all you are done with and what are you looking for. :)

Comment: FB.Event.subscribe will be helpful to you; use comment.create/remove
Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/